# Power of a complex number, find $(\sqrt{3} + i)^{99}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Question: let $$z = \sqrt{3} + i. $$ Find $$z^{99}.$$ Put your answer in $$a + bi$$ form.

My work:
$$r = 2$$
$$z = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)
 = (2(\cos(\pi/6) + \sin(\pi/6))^{99}
 = 2^{99}(\cos(99\pi/6) + i \sin(99\pi/6))$$

Now to get it back to the $$a + bi$$ form, what do I do with the $99$?

Comment: An essential duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2015326/11619)

Comment: And also of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1978915/11619).

Answer (score 8):

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{99\pi}{6} = \frac{33\pi}{2} = \left( 16+\frac12 \right) \pi$, so $$z^{99} = 2^{99}(\cos(99\pi/6) + i\sin(99\pi/6)) = 2^{99} (\cos(\pi/2) + i\sin(\pi/2)) = 2^{99}i,$$
which is pure imaginary.

Comment: thank you! Is this universal for all questions like this?

Comment: @P.Layton Yes, in a finding powers for complex numbers, you first calculate $|z|$ and $\theta = \arg z$, then apply [De Moivre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) $${\displaystyle {\big (}\cos(x)+i\sin(x){\big )}^{n}=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx).}$$

Comment: I meant, for the part where you bring in the $$n$$ value. I tend to get stuck on that part.

Comment: @P.Layton As the other two answers suggest, take "mod $2\pi$".  i.e. substract it by integral multiples of $2\pi$ to that the angle is between $0$ and $2 \pi$, then calculate the trigo function

Answer (score 5):

*Hint*:  $\frac{99\pi}6=8\cdot2\pi+\frac\pi2$

And $\sin$ and $\cos$ are periodic of period $2\pi$...

Answer (score 5):

Alt. hint:  for a shortcut in this particular case, note that:

$$\require{cancel}
\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)^3= \bcancel{\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^3}+3\cdot\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2i + \bcancel{3 \cdot \sqrt{3}i^2}+i^3=9 \cdot i-i = 8i
$$

Then of course $\;\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)^{99}=\left(\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)^3\right)^{33}=\ldots\,$

Answer (score 1):

Leave the $99$ in the exponent of $2$, and calculate which of the twelve angles ($0,\frac\pi6,\dots,\frac{11\pi}6$) the $\frac{99\pi}6$ falls modulo $2\pi$.