# How do I find large powers of complex numbers using a+bi

Tags: complex-numbers

I am always stuck on finding large powers of complex numbers, for example:

Let z = $(\sqrt{3}+i)$.  Find $z^{99}$ and express your answer in the form
$"a+bi"$.

Is there a trick in solving these?  Can I use polar form in solving this?

Comment: Yes.  Switch to polar, grind it out, switch back.

Comment: Have you learned DeMoivre's law?  How about Euler's identity?

Comment: @DougM If I use DeMoivre's Law, that would give a maximum of 4 roots correct?  Then I can just add them all up for my answer.

Comment: $z = 2(\cos \frac {\pi}{6} + i\sin\frac {\pi}{6}), z^{99} = 2^{99}(\cos \frac {99\pi}{6} + i\sin\frac {99\pi}{6}) = 2^{99}(\cos \frac {\pi}{2} + i\sin\frac {\pi}{2})$

Comment: @DougM sorry for keep asking but how did you get $\frac {\pi}{2}?$

Comment: Both sine and cosine are periodic with period $2\pi$ so you can subtract off as many $2\pi$s as you want from the argument of each.  He also took out a common factor of $3$.

Comment: @RossMillikan alright I see it now thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727081/power-of-a-complex-number-find-sqrt3-i99